# How can list all the attribute in a table that do not contain a specific string in another table in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to list all the `PolicyID` in a `Policy` table excepts the `PolicyID` which contains `jewels`.
There are 3 tables:

```
1.Policy (PolicyID)

2.ContentGroup(ContentGroupID,Description) 

3.ContentItem(PolicyID,ContentGroupID)
```

In `Description` contains "`jewels`"
Here my code:

```
SELECT A.PolicyID, A.EffectiveFromDate, A.PropertyId
FROM (Policy AS A INNER JOIN ContentItem AS C ON A.PolicyID = C.PolicyID) 
INNER JOIN ContentGroup as G 
ON C.ContentGroupID = G.ContentGroupID
WHERE NOT G.Description IN (SELECT Description FROM ContentGroup as G WHERE G.Description Like "jewels")
GROUP BY A.PolicyID, A.EffectiveFromDate, A.PropertyId;
```

When I run the code i still display all policies which are include `jewels`. And i have tried some different method like `Not like`, `!=` to `Jewels` but it seem not working for MS access

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want aggregation with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT P.PolicyID, P.EffectiveFromDate, P.PropertyId
FROM (Policy AS P INNER JOIN
      ContentItem AS C
      ON P.PolicyID = CI.PolicyID
     ) INNER JOIN
     ContentGroup as G 
     ON CG.ContentGroupID = CG.ContentGroupID
GROUP BY A.PolicyID, A.EffectiveFromDate, A.PropertyId
HAVING SUM(IIF(CG.Description Like "jewels", 1, 0)) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause is counting the number of rows in each group that have a description of `"jewels"`.  The `= 0` is saying that there are none.

Comment: It's working even though the last clause i'm not quite familar with that why the number 1,0 right next to the "jewels".